# OnActionExecutionAsync in IAsyncActionFilter only hit sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, attributes, authorization

I have made an Api Key authorization attribute, and it works... sometimes, which is quite strange.

The attribute code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ApiKeyAuthAttribute: Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        private const string ApiKeyHeadername = "ApiKey"; 
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            DataAcces dataAcces = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(DataAcces)) as DataAcces;

            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(ApiKeyHeadername, out var apiKey) ||
                !dataAcces.TryAuthenticate(apiKey, out NsInvoiceRecognitionCredentials credentials))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }
            ((JobController)context.Controller).Credentials = credentials;

            await next();
        }
    }
```

The controller code:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("jobs")]
    [ApiKeyAuth]
    public class JobController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataAcces _dataAcces;
        private readonly ILogger<JobController> _logger;
        public NsInvoiceRecognitionCredentials Credentials;

        public JobController(ILogger<JobController> logger, DataAcces dataAcces)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dataAcces = dataAcces;
        }

        [HttpPost, Route("add")]
        public IActionResult Add(IFormFile document)
        {
            //Do stuff
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

DataAcces code:

```
        public bool TryAuthenticate(string apiKeyString, out NsInvoiceRecognitionCredentials credentials)
        {
            if (Guid.TryParse(apiKeyString, out Guid apiKey))
            {
                credentials = _dbContext.Set<NsInvoiceRecognitionCredentials>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApiKey == apiKey);
                return credentials != null;
            }
            credentials = default;
            return false;
        }
```

Every request I send ends up in the controller constructor, which is expected. After that it *should* go to `OnActionExecutionAsync` in the `ApiKeyAut hAttribute`, but this does not happen 100% of the time, only about 50% of the time. The other 50% of the time it just does nothing and eventually time out.

I don't think the problem is in my filter or the dataAcces code, just because it doesnt even hit my breakpoint on the first line of OnActionExecutionAsync in my filter, so those parts are not even executed.

If I place a breakpoint in the first line of my controller constructor I can step over the next few lines, and about 50% of the time it just stops after those lines are executed, no exception, nothing.

EDIT:

I figured out what is going wrong, I didnt find a proper solution yet. I'll answer my question if I do.

There was nothing going wrong in the filter, the problems all occured due to the fact that I am working with files in the request body. These files apparently made the request too heavy (strange because its only 100kb). When I send requests without any files, it all works fine.

I think the problem might be the way I am sending and receiving files (IFormFiles)

If anyone knows why, or how to fix this I would be most grateful

Comment: Your code needs more details. Please post some explanations and maybe code for your 
 DataAcces service . TryAuthenticate method for example.

Comment: I added the dataAcces code, I dont think that is the problem because its not executed at all, if you need more explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it OnActionExecutingAsync and you have to use it like this

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiKeyAuthAttribute))]
 public class JobController : ControllerBase
```

And before using it should be registered in startup

```
 services.AddScoped<ApiKeyAuthAttribute>();
```

bur it usually makes sense to use filter only for the action where it is needed

```
  [ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiKeyAuthAttribute))]
 public  async Task<IActionResult> GetUData()
```

and maybe you will have to remove all extra attributes. And I don't see any async tasks in your controller. Maybe you  can try just ActionFilter

```
 public class ApiKeyAuthAttribute: IActionFilter
{
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
```

or you can try to merge both

```
 public class ApiKeyAuthAttribute: IActionFilter, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
    ......
    }
    public async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, 
     ActionExecutionDelegate next)
   {
    OnActionExecuting(context);
     await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this did improve it, it now works about 75% of the time...

Comment: I am using it for the  action. Try to  move it to the action

Comment: When using it for the action the same thing happens. Postman tells me it can't get a response when it happens

Comment: Then if your filter is  still not working properly the bug is in the filter code. Your algorithm doesn't make proper filtration. YOu have to explain clearly what is this filter for and how it is supposed to work.

Comment: The filter is supposed to check incoming requests for the api key and check if it is valid and present in the database. If not, it should return a 401 unauthorized before the request reaches the controller method. I dont think the bug is in the filter code, because when the bug occurs the filter code is not even executed. it just stops after constructing the controller.

Comment: Changing it to sync seems to solve it. I don't really know yet if I am going to be needing async controller methods. I still think its kind of strange that this even happened in the first place, how can something only work sometimes..  Thank you for your input!

Comment: @WesselOttevanger You can try to put both in one class. " ApiKeyAuthAttribute: IActionFilter, IAsyncActionFilter" I never tryed it so please let me know how it works

Comment: Oh I thought changing it to sync solved the problem, but it just didnt happen for a while.  It still happens :(   I did try putting both the Async and sync version in at the same time, but it just always chooses the async over the sync, even on sync endpoints.

Comment: @WesselOttevanger Try to change from actionexecuted to actionexecuting. It couldn' t select only one since they were different stages of execution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233016/discussion-between-wessel-ottevanger-and-serge).

Comment: Hey @Serge, Thanks for the help. It didnt solve my problem but it definitely set me on the right path. I figured out the problem isnt actually in the filter, but in the request handling itself. The problem only occurs when I am sending files. small files work fine, but over 100kb is when the problems happen. I answered my own question and will edit it when I find a proper solution to the problem, I'll send you a message when I do if you're interested.